# Counting: addition rule vs subtraction rule

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

> Suppose there are 5 letters, ABCDE, and we want to use these 5 letters to from a strings of length 3.

Question: how many strings contain the letter A, allowing repetitions?

My solution: $1 \times 5\times5 + 5\times1\times5 + 5\times5\times1$, the reasoning that I come up with the solution is because since there are only 3 spots available, so we fix A to be one of each spots every single time, and fill the remaining spots with 5 available letters, and apply addition principle to it, so the final solution is 75.

Official solution: $5^3 - 4^3 = 61$.

I am not sure if my thought is correct or not,  I think my solution is not correct because that addition principle requires sets to be pair-wisely disjoint, since there might exist over-counting in my solution, so the actual solution is less than my solution.

Is my thoughts about my mistake correct? I just want some clarification here.

Comment: Yes, the problem is double counting.  You count the string AAB twice, once for the first A and once for the second.  You are counting the number of A's that appear in all $3$-letter strings, rather than the number of $3$-letter strings containing an A.

Answer (score 1):

You are counting duplicates every time you select $A$ at another place after fixing $A$ already. More precisely, you counted each permutation of $AAB$ and $AAC$ twice giving $12$ extra along with $AAA$ $2$ extra times giving $75-14=61$

Instead of searching for all exceptions, the best approach here will be to use inclusion-exclusion principle as done in the Official Answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your method works providing you are careful not to double count.  You can use the following
$$1 \times 5\times5 + 4\times1\times5 + 4\times4\times1=61.$$

Note that in the second term you only have $4$ choices for the first letter since you have already counted those which have $A$ in that position. Then in the third term you only have $4$ choices for the first two letters since you have already counted those which have an $A$ in one of those positions.